# ASP.NET MVC 3 localization with DisplayAttribute and custom resource provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, internationalization, displayattribute

I use a custom resource provider to get resource strings from a database. This works fine with ASP.NET where I can define the resource type as a string. The metadata attributes for model properties in MVC 3 (like [Range], [Display], [Required] require the type of a Resource as a parameter, where the ResourceType is the type of the generated code-behind class of a .resx file.

```
    [Display(Name = "Phone", ResourceType = typeof(MyResources))]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
```

Because I don't have .resx files, such a class does not exist. How can I use the model attributes with a custom resource provider?

I would like to have something like this:

```
    [Display(Name = "Telefon", ResourceTypeName = "MyResources")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
```

The DisplayNameAttribute from System.ComponentModel had a overridable DisplayName Property for this purpose, but the DisplayAttribute class is sealed. For the validation attributes no corresponding classes exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend the DisplayNameAttribute and override the DisplayName string property. I have something like this

```
    public class LocalizedDisplayName : DisplayNameAttribute
    {
        private string DisplayNameKey { get; set; }   
        private string ResourceSetName { get; set; }   

        public LocalizedDisplayName(string displayNameKey)
            : base(displayNameKey)
        {
            this.DisplayNameKey = displayNameKey;
        }


        public LocalizedDisplayName(string displayNameKey, string resourceSetName)
            : base(displayNameKey)
        {
            this.DisplayNameKey = displayNameKey;
            this.ResourceSetName = resourceSetName;
        }

        public override string DisplayName
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.GlobalResourceSetName))
                {
                    return MyHelper.GetLocalLocalizedString(this.DisplayNameKey);
                }
                else
                {
                    return MyHelper.GetGlobalLocalizedString(this.DisplayNameKey, this.ResourceSetName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For `MyHelper`, the methods can be something like this:

```
public string GetLocalLocalizedString(string key){
    return _resourceSet.GetString(key);
}
```

Obviously you will need to add error handling and have the `resourceReader` set up. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542(v=vs.110).aspx)

With this, you then decorate your model with the new attribute, passing the key of the resource you want to get the value from, like this

```
[LocalizedDisplayName("Title")]
```

Then the `Html.LabelFor` will display the localized text automatically.

Comment: i think you forgot to put the code for "MyHelper.GetLocalLocalizedString"

Comment: I know this is going zombie but you deserve more internets for this.

Answer (score 7):

The most cleanest way I came up with is to override `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`. Here's a very neat article on how to do this.

http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/14/creating-your-own-modelmetadataprovider-to-handle-custom-attributes/

Comment: would you show us how you managed to write that. The article shows how to add a new data notation, but doesn't show anything about localization

Answer (score 2):

I think you would have to override the DataAnnotations properties to localize them with a DB resource provider. You could inherit from the current ones, and then specify further properties such as DB connection string to use when getting the resources from your custom provider.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work as the DisplayAttribute is a sealed class. Even if I do my own implementation for the attribute I would have to overwrite the Html Extension methods (e.g. Html.LabelFor) as well.

Comment: I made further investigations: I could derive from DisplayNameAttribute which has an overrideble property DisplayName. In the end I used a T4 template to generate the Resources class because I don't have to implement all data annotation attributes.