# Apply localization through resource files to DisplayAttribute 

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, variables, static, constants

I've started a default MVC4 project in Visual Studio,

Somewhere in my model is this piece of code

```
 public class LoginModel
 {
    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
  }
```

I want to change it to something like this because i want to try localization (which works within another class, but not here) (strings=resx file for localization)

```
public class LoginModel
 {
    [Required]
    [Display(Name =strings.UserName)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = strings.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = strings.RememberMe)]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
  }
```

The error is it must be a constant expression, but when I make it like that, then I get something like 'property index lacks accessor'

What am I missing here?? Why cant I just assign a string value to the darn thing?
In Java this is all so much easier. Hope you can help me out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Localization of DisplayNameAttribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356464/localization-of-displaynameattribute)

Comment: thanks!! that post solved my problems, i had searched, but i guess i didnt search right. I had to use 
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(strings), Name = "Gebruikersnaam")]
and i made the strings.resx attributes all public

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use Resources.
In attributes you can set only immutable values.

Try this.

```
[Display(Name = "Remember me?", ResourceType = typeof(YourResourcesType))]
public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
```

And look this
[ASP.NET MVC 3 localization with DisplayAttribute and custom resource provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872309/asp-net-mvc-3-localization-with-displayattribute-and-custom-resource-provider)

Comment: i already had the solution (see comment under question), but you are right, this is how to solve this problem.

Answer (score -8):

I think you must use sessions and viewState,

To use sessions Visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

And to use viewstate Visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx