# Using the name data annotation vs hard coding in view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations

I have the following in my EntityFramework Domain Models:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[Required]
[Display(Name = "Last Name")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

And in My view I do the following:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
```

But I was wondering, why is it preferred to specify the "Display Name" in my model instead of just writing the Label manually in the View page?

I can actually see this causing more problems, what if in 6 months time someone comes to me and says "We don't want it to say First Name anymore, we want it to say "Your First Name" I would either have to revert to hard coding it in my view or recompile my Model Project for the change to take effect..

Is there any benefits I am not aware of for using data annotations?

Comment: I'm going to say this.  I've got an ASP.NET MVC project that's 2 years old.  I'm actually regretting using the Data Annotations.  Every time we find so much as a spelling mistake we've got to recompile the site.  Given that for love nor money I can get the combination of EF/ASP.NET's cold start time down to less than 30 seconds this is a complete pain in the bum!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The benefit of `DisplayAttribute` is localization like the code below.

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "First Name", ResourceType = typeof(YourResources)))]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

[ASP.NET MVC 3 localization with DisplayAttribute and custom resource provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872309/asp-net-mvc-3-localization-with-displayattribute-and-custom-resource-provider) has some good answers about localization and different way to achieve it.

Answer (score 3):

The benefit is simply [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

So you currently use it in a single place, your edit page.  Now add:

- multiple validation messages (First Name is required etc)
- a view (read-only) page
- a list page
- a summary / tooltip
- a reference on another page
- logging/tracing
- a breadcrumb (okay, pushing it a bit here)

now you have to change it in 15+ places, chances of missing one... high
[chances of a typo in one or more of those... not low]

So in each of those you use reference the DisplayName rather than typing it in manually... now you only have to change it in... 1 place.